# java split with Greedy quantifiers

Tags: java, split

Anyone can explain the 12 outputs step by step?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] splitStrs = "booo:and:fooo1o".split("o*", -1); 
    printOutput(splitStrs);
}

static void printOutput(String[] input) {
        System.out.println("count:" + input.length);
        Stream.of(input).map(s -> "\"" + s + "\",").forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();   
}
```

output:

> count:12
> "b","",":","a","n","d",":","f","","1","","",

Answer (score 2):

I found your output a little hard to read so I did it this way. `o*` will match on any string of `o's` including none (The `*` quantifier is 0 or more). So any place that didn't have a `o` was simply splitting on the space between any two characters.  So `ab` would yield `a` and `b`

Here is what may be confusing.  Consider the string `boooob` and the split uses `o*`.

- the first split is at the beginning of the line which matches empty string (or `null`) and `oooo`.  So `b` is returned.
- the second split is between the previous `oooo` and `b` which is empty, so an empty string is returned.
- the third split is before and after `b` (empty on both sides), so `b` is returned.
- the fourth split is after `b` and it matches null.  It is a trailing match delimiter and returns "" because of your -1.

So the above would return an array of `{"b","","b",""}`.  You would get the exact same results no matter how long your string of `o's` were between the two `b's`.

What you may have been expecting is splitting on `o+` which, using -1 again, would return `{"b",":and:f","1",""}`.

So

```
val    split string

"b"    ""    
""     "ooo" 
":"    ""    
"a"    ""    
"n"    ""    
"d"    ""    
":"    ""    
"f"    ""    
""     "ooo" 
"1"    ""    
""     "o"   
""     ""
```

Here is the code used to generate the the above.  I pasted the second grouping to the right of the first.

Results of the split.

```
String str = "booo:and:fooo1o";
String[] s = str.split("o*",-1);
String[] result = Arrays.stream(s).map(a->"\""+a+"\"").toArray(String[]::new);
for (String st : result) {
     System.out.println(st);
}
```

Capture of the split string.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(o*)").matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("\""+m.group(1)+"\"");
}
```

Comment: if it is greedy, then all split string "","ooo", "",....., "" all match 0*, why it will split so many times as your result?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.